# unsupported operand type(s) for //: 'function' and 'int' python projectile

Tags: python

```
if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        
  if man.Left:
    facing = -1
  else:
   facing = 1
    if len(fireBalls) < 5:
       fireBalls.append(Projectile( round(man.x + man.width //2),      round( man.y + man.height //2),        6,          (0,0,0),        facing))
```

Comment: please edit your post with the full error traceback

Comment: seems like `man.width()` is a function you have to call with parentheses

Comment: What is `man`? Assuming the error is in the code you've shown (traceback please!), in `man.width // 2` suggests that `man.width` is a function.

Answer (score 0):

As a few of the comments state, `man.width` is a function. I assume it returns a numeric type. If you want to actually get the return value of the function, you must use `man.width()` to actually call the function.

IE

```py
class ManThing(object):
    def width(self):
        return 3

man = ManThing()

print(type(man.width))
# <class 'method'>
print(type(man.width()))
# <class 'int'>
print(man.width)
# <bound method ManThing.width of <__main__.ManThing object at 0x7fd2ecb6bd60>>
print(man.width())
# 3
```